# Can this laptop run WoW and SC2?

Tags: gaming

I was wondering if this computer can run World of Warcraft and StarCraft 2. If so, what estimates on fps would I get? If you're looking for a location in World of Warcraft, lets say you were in Dalaran. I'd greatly appreciate the help.

http://www.retrevo.com/search?q=Toshiba+A505D-S6008&rt=sp&modelid=23611682

EDIT: If you're looking for the computer's specs, there's a tab below the computer image.

Comment: This is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You should try asking here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

from all that ive read it should be able to, but to re check if u have an intel processor, intel's site has a "can i run it" feature, as doese AMD's, you could check that for any future capability questions

Answer (score 0):

It should run those two games.